# What this schema is called and how to make Rich schema?

Tags: html, json, schema, meta-tags

I am working on Google Rich Text Results but I cannot figure out how to make this section.

[image]

Google [test of rich result](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results?id=ugn_AZQkJfj61iYFwAtiQg) shows only the rating and price part and this is the schema for that

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name" : "Samsung Galaxy Note 10",
    "productID":"2121",
    "url"  : "https://priceoye.pk/mobiles/samsung/samsung-galaxy-note-10",
    "image": "https://images.priceoye.pk/samsung-galaxy-note-10-pakistan-priceoye-cg7be.jpg",
    "category" : "Mobiles",
    "gtin" : "",
    "gtin13" : "",
    "brand" : "Samsung","offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "price" : "169999",
        "priceCurrency": "PKR",
        "itemCondition":"https://schema.org/NewCondition",
        "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
        "url": "https://priceoye.pk/mobiles/samsung/samsung-galaxy-note-10"
    },"aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "bestRating": "5",
        "ratingValue": "5",
        "ratingCount": "1"
        },"review": [],"description" : "The Samsung Galaxy Note 10 has a 6.3 inches screen and 256GB 8GB RAM RAM. It comes with 3500 Mah battery and yes back camera.",
    "sku": "samsung-galaxy-note-10"
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The test result does not display the same URL in the screenshot, are they the same`?

Comment: @empiric Yes, both sites show the same results on google. I have updated my question and added the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Look at: https://schema.org/Product

There you find the list of all schemas for a product. Its the schema ***weight***.

Comment: But the weight is not in the JSON I shared above. so where the weight is coming from?